# PHP function convention

Tags: php, function, memory

have a quick question, does initiating a function in PHP the following way:

```
function test(){
 ... some data ...
};
```

comparing to the following which gets assigned to memory only when program reaches it:

```
$test2 = function(){
 ...some data...
}
```

what is better for performance and in general for memory also?

Comment: how could the second one possibly be faster? it's doing more work.

Comment: second one looks javascript-ish to me :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try this out yourself with [memory_get_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) to see what give you better results.

Test 1:

```
function test(){};

echo memory_get_usage();
```

Test 2:

```
$test2 = function(){};

echo memory_get_usage();
```

Comment: Nice answer... Just to improve the answer, you should provide the documentation about `memory_get_usage`

Comment: i like the way you think